# Error al tratar de insertar registro con una consulta preparada en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysqli

La idea del codigo es insertar un usuario con su nombre y apellido a la base de datos, estoy usando consultas preparadas, asi evito la inyeccion de SQL pero al llegar a `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` me lanza el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference

**Codigo `PHP`:**

```
<?php

$nom = $_POST['nombre'];
$ape = $_POST['apellido'];

require("conexion.php");

$conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Fallo al conectar con la BBDD";
    exit();
}

mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die ("No se encuntra la BBDD");

mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf-8");

$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (id,nombre, ap) VALUES (?,?,?)";

$resultado = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $sql);

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($resultado, 'iss', 1, $nom, $ape);

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_execute($resultado);

if($stmt == false){
    echo "Error al ejecutar la consulta";
}else{
    echo "Nombre y apellido registrado exitosamente.";

    mysqli_stmt_close($resultado);
}
```

**TABLA`SQL`:**

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios (
    id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL ,
    nombre varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ap varchar(50) NOT NULL,

   CONSTRAINT pk_usuarios PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: cuando el `id` es PK y `AUTO_INCREMENT` no se debe colocar en la sentencia sql y tampoco pasarle un valor, pues el gestor es quien se lo asignará

Comment: veo al inicio que declaras un `require` a un archivo `conexion.php` pero después aquí mismo haces la conexión, el otro archivo que tiene? las variables de conexión y sus valores respectivos?

Comment: Si, contiene las variables de conexion y sus valores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontre la solución, lo que pasa es que no habia que pasarle ningun parametro `id` en el `insert` ni en el `bind_param`

**CODIGO PHP**

```
<?php

$nom = $_POST['nombre'];
$ape = $_POST['apellido'];

require("conexion.php");

$conexion = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_usuario, $db_contra);

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Fallo al conectar con la BBDD";
    exit();
}

mysqli_select_db($conexion, $db_nombre) or die ("No se encuntra la BBDD");

mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf-8");

$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, ap) VALUES (?,?)";

$resultado = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $sql);

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($resultado, 'ss',$nom, $ape);

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_execute($resultado);

if($stmt == false){
    echo "Error al ejecutar la consulta";
}else{
    echo "Nombre y apellido registrado exitosamente.";

    mysqli_stmt_close($resultado);
}
```

Comment: Claro, hay que pasar a la consulta tantos valores como signos `?`  haya en ella y cada valor debe ir en el lugar en que aparece en la consulta. Y, `bind_param` tampoco admite valores pasados directamente, tienen que ser variables siempre.